# Linear Maps and Dimension

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional. Let $v \in V$. Let
$E = \{T \in \mathsf{L}(V, W) \mid Tv = 0\}$.

(a) Show that $E$ is a subspace of $\mathsf{L}(V, W)$.

(b) Suppose $v \ne 0$. What is $\dim E$?

Part a) is not a problem for me. Part b) on the other hand... I was given a hint that if $v$ is not equal to $0$ then we can extend it to a basis for $V$. We can also fix a basis for $W$. I just don't know how to use this hint to solve part b? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know how to find the matrix of a linear transformation with respect to a certain basis?

Comment: Do you know what the dimension of $Hom(U,V)$ is?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes I do!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis and $\{w_1,\dots,w_m\}$ a basis for $W$, then the transformations $f_{ij}$ satisfying
$$
f_{ij}(v_k) = \begin{cases}
w_j & k=i\\
0 & k \neq 0
\end{cases}
$$
form a basis of $L(V,W)$.

---

Alternatively: if we fix the above bases with $v_1 = v$, then $L(V,W)$ is identified space of $m \times n$ matrices (of transformations with respect to this basis).  We can identify $E$ with those matrices whose first column is zero.

Comment: I don't understand how to write out that transformation. That's my problem

Comment: See my latest edit.